# How to create a public post with Facebooks feed dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facebook's feed dialog to prompt a user to share a link to their facebook wall (
[Facebook's feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/))

but when I try view the post when I'm logged in as a different user I get an error saying the page does not exist. I'm assuming this is because I'm not a 'friend' of the person that made the original post (using the feed dialog).

My question is: is there a way to set the feed dialog to make the post public and viewable to everyone and not just their friends?

Comment: When dialog is shown u have the option to set the privacy on the bottom right corner of the window. I don think you can set this explicitly using code.

Comment: Ok I see that little icon there now where the user can set the privacy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, only the user has the privileges to determinate the post visibility